# SQLAlchemy Replicate Client Side Method on SQL-Side

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Note: This is a simplified example of what I'm actually trying to do here.

I have the following Parent-Child relationship both driven off a declarative_base.

```
class Parent(declartive_base):

    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _children = relationship("Child", lazy='dynamic')

    def total_for_date(self, date):

        return sum([child.num for child in self._children.filter(Child.date == date)])

    @classmethod
    def total_for_date_query(cls, date):

        #TODO Return a query that represents this...
        pass

class Child(declarative_base):

    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    num = Column(Integer)

    date = Column(Date)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    _parent = relationship("Parent")
```

I'd like to calculate a total of a certain number associated with a child given a parent query. This can be performed via python as such

```
q = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id_([4,5,10,...]))

total = sum([parent.total_for_date(datetime.date(2018, 1, 2)) for parent in q.all()])
```

However, the computation here is done in python and given a large amount of data, won't perform as well compared to SQL.

I'm trying to figure out a way using hybrid expressions, selects, sqlalchemy queries etc. to have an equivalent method on the parent that returns a query/selectable/expression that will allow me to perform the computation on the SQL side, but maintain a similar interface compared to the other method.

In this example, I'd would like to do the following instead.

```
q = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id.in_([4,5,10]))

total = q.select_entity_from(Parent.total_for_date_query(datetime.date(2018, 1, 2))).scalar()

#Note idk if "select_entity_from" is what I want here
```

But I don't know how to fill out the SQL-side method equivalent `total_for_date_query`. I just can't seem to wrap my head around when to use a `Query` vs. `Selectable`, hybrid property expressions vs. hybrid method expressions etc.

Comment: Could you please refine your question in to a verifiable example? There are some obvious typing errors, and some confusing configurations (relationship to *Node* in *Child*, instead of *Parent*, and a `back_populates=`, though the relationship in *Parent* is dynamic). Make it so that others can pretty much simply copy/paste your example, run it, and verify your current results.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Edited to remove `Node` ref and `back_populates`.